# Will :last-child work on the last list item in an unordered list?

Tags: html, css

if this is the html:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

and this is the css:

```
ul li
{
  margin-right:5px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
}
```

Is there a way to use :last-child so there is no margin-right on the last list item?

I tried

```
ul li:last-child
{
  margin-right:0px;
}
```

and it didn't work.  How would this pseudo-selector be used on a li element?

Comment: I presume you have extra code like `display: inline` on the `li`?

Comment: You're asking about removing the left margin, but your CSS talks about a right margin...

Comment: try `ul li:last-child`.  there is no `ui`; only `ol` and `ul`.

Comment: yeah - sorry - float:left, and display:block.

Comment: cleaned up my question more.  couple of typos

Comment: What is your browser? IE versions lower than 9 do not support `:last-child`.

Comment: Consider using `:first-child`, and `margin-left` for `LI + LI`. This will work in IE7+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:last-child` isn’t supported in:

- IE 8 and below
- Opera 9 and below
- Safari 3 and below

http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/:last-child

Are you using one of those browsers?

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in your rule. It says `ui` but should be `ul`. And it should work fine.

Here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Ggf4P/)**.

Comment: It works in firefox and not IE8 - that was the problem.  I did have typos in my original question - but not in the source code I was working on.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: What version of IE? IE8 and below don't understand :last-child.

Answer (score 2):

you misspelled your css

You have

```
ui li:last-child
```

and it should be

```
ul li:last-child
```

And your question is asking about margin-left, but your css is showing us margin-right